# xampp- unable to start apache on ubuntu 16

Tags: apache2, lamp, xampp

1.sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.2-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

2. whenever i type netstat -tulpn | grep ':80\|:443'
   the output is
   (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
   will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
3. when i type this /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
   the post is still not saving

please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to find process id using sudo. Processes which are occupied by other users, their pid can not be seen to rest of the users. Only root can see these. As you have used sudo to start lampp, I am assuming you are a sudo user.

> ```
> sudo netstat -lnp | grep :80
> sudo netstat -lnp | grep :3306
> ```

Now you will be able to see both pids. You need to kill those processes.

```
sudo kill -9 <pid1>
sudo kill -9 <pid2>
```

2. If there are no processes running on respective ports but still same warning is visible, you can remove pid files manually.

> ```
> sudo rm /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid
> sudo rm /opt/lampp/var/mysql/<hostname>.pid
> ```

Comment: thankyou so much. as i am new to ubuntu, i was unable to find the port number and kill those process that was using the post 80. thankyou once again