# my apache server is not starting

Tags: xampp

Every time it fails

```
afsan@afsan-linux:~/Downloads$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.11-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

even i tried this:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

but doesn't work
i also tried this link [xampp- unable to start apache on ubuntu 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159758/xampp-unable-to-start-apache-on-ubuntu-16)
but I'm running kubuntu 19.10

Comment: This error is self-explanatory: `XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.` - something else is already listening on port 80 or whatever port xampp listens on by default.  You have to identify that process/service, and disable it / stop it in order to run the Apache2 as part of lamp.

Comment: You also failed to grep properly.  `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` is the full thing you want to run to get what's listening on that port.

Comment: Or `sudo lsof -i tcp:80`